GTranslate Plugin Compatibility Issue with Integrated Lazy Page Speed in WordPress
I'm experiencing a compatibility issue between the Lazy Page Speed feature integrated into my theme and the GTranslate plugin on my WordPress site. Specifically, the Lazy Page Speed optimization is altering the  tag for the GTranslate plugin, which causes it to malfunction. The altered  tag appears as follows:
<script data-laps-action="reorder" type="javascript/blocked" id="gt_widget_script_XXXX-js-before">

Whereas it should normally appear like this:
<script id="gt_widget_script_XXXX-js-before">

This alteration prevents the GTranslate plugin from displaying correctly, causing issues with the language switcher and flag icons on the front-end of the site. After inspecting the issue, I confirmed that disabling the Lazy Page Speed feature resolves the problem. However, I would like to keep Lazy Page Speed enabled for the rest of the site’s performance optimizations while resolving the issue with GTranslate.
I tried disabling the Lazy Page Speed feature and found that it resolved the issue with the GTranslate plugin. However, I did not want to completely disable the optimization because it is critical for improving my site's performance. Instead, I was hoping to find a way to:
> Exclude or adjust the optimization specifically for the GTranslate plugin, so that the Lazy Page Speed optimization doesn't interfere with it.
> Ensure that the rest of the site still benefits from the performance enhancements provided by Lazy Page Speed.

I am looking for a solution that allows both Lazy Page Speed and GTranslate to work together without causing issues on the site.
